# How to solve the problem of $(a,a)$ in the Kuratowski formalisation of ordered pairs?

Tags: set-theory

$(a,a)={\{{\{a\}},{\{a,a}\}}\}={\{\{{a}\},{\{a}\}}\}={\{\{a}\}\}$

Is this any problem in Kuratowski formalisation? If yes, how to solve it?

Comment: There is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a problem. The only thing that is needed for the Kuratowski definition to work is that we can prove
$$ \forall z,a,b,x,y \bigl( z=(a,b) \land z=(x,y) \implies a=x \land b=y \bigr) $$
or in other words, that we can "decode" the meaning of an ordered pair uniquely.

A Kuratowski pair that is a set $\{p,q\}$ with two *different* elements must be of the form $(x,y)$ with $x\ne y$. To decode the pair, we can see that one of $p$ and $q$ must be a singleton; its element is $x$. The *other* element of the pair is must have exactly two elements; $y$ is the one of its elements that is not $x$.

A Kuradowski pair that is a set with *exactly one* element must be of the form $(x,x)$, and $x$ is then the unique element of the element of the pair.

Something of the form $\{A\}$ where $A$ is not a singleton is not a Kuratowski pair at all.